# docker-engine conflicts with packages

Tags: docker

I have installed docker-engine . Then i removed the package with apt-purge docker-engine command. 
so after it i see the following conflicts

```
aptitude show docker-engine
Package: docker-engine                   
State: not installed
Version: 1.8.3-0~trusty
Priority: N/A
Section: N/A
Maintainer: Docker <support@docker.com>
Architecture: amd64
Uncompressed Size: 28,5 M
Depends: iptables, init-system-helpers (>= 1.13~), sysv-rc (>=     2.88dsf-24) | file-rc (>=
     0.8.16), perl, libapparmor1 (>= 2.6~devel), libc6 (>= 2.14), libdevmapper1.02.1 (>=
     2:1.02.63), libsqlite3-0 (>= 3.5.9)
Recommends: aufs-tools, ca-certificates, cgroupfs-mount | cgroup-lite, git, xz-utils, apparmor
Conflicts: docker (< 1.5~), docker (< 1.5~), docker.io, docker.io, lxc-     docker, lxc-docker,
       lxc-docker-virtual-package, lxc-docker-virtual-package
```

But `aptitude show lxc-docker`says that **No current or candidate version found for lxc-docker**
Package: lxc-docker
State: not a real package

the same error for all conflicting packages

Comment: docker has had several names, previous versions were lxc-docker, and 1.9 is docker-engine, aptitude is right

Answer (score 1):

docker has had several names, previous versions were named lxc-docker, and 1.9 (and more recent) is docker-engine, aptitude is right

and if you want go to the latest docker `aptitude install --only-upgrade docker-engine`

Answer (score 0):

Use **dpkg to view all installed packages** named with *docker*:

```
$ dpkg -l|grep docker
```

You should see only:

- docker (not the container but: System tray for KDE3/GNOME2 docklet applications)
- docker-engine (the open-source application container engine)

If you see: lxc-docker or docker.io, you should **purge them**:

```
$ sudo apt-get purge lxc-docker
$ sudo apt-get purge docker.io
```