# What's the difference when installing docker with 2 of these following command?

Tags: docker

When it comes to install Docker on centos, i found 2 different ways to do it.

The first one is : `yum install docker-engine`

The second one is: `yum install docker-io`

And in case i installed docker using the first one, it i continue with the second one the error appeared, like this:

```
Error: docker-engine conflicts with docker-1.8.2-10.el7.centos.x86_64
Error: docker-engine-selinux conflicts with docker-selinux-1.8.2-10.el7.centos.x86_64
```

So anyone can tell me what's the difference  between them?

Comment: It seems that the docker package changes names quite a bit. The current name is "docker-engine". Use that one. The others are probably just there for legacy support (to provide updates to people that have installed "docker-io" or "lxc-docker") http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33316662/docker-engine-conflicts-with-packages

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This dates back [from June 2015](https://github.com/garethr/garethr-docker/issues/310), when [Docker announced](http://blog.docker.com/2015/07/new-apt-and-yum-repos/) "New Apt and Yum Repos"

That is when new packages ([like the one for CentOS](https://yum.dockerproject.org/repo/main/centos/6/Packages/)) were named docker-engine (initially to replace `lxc-docker*`)